# Opening port 1723 on Foundation Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, port-forwarding

I am trying to set up VPN on our server but something strange seems to be going on with port 1723. We are not on a typical internet connection: the connection is broadcast over radio transmitters and so a CAT5 cable comes straight into the office and we just plug it into a switch. The provider handles DHCP, port forwarding and seperates all the different networks. So we don't have a router. Our provider has opened every TCP and UDP port and forwarded it our servers IP (i know we don't need every port but it wasn't working so we decided to do this temporarily).

However, something is blocking port 1723. The required rules are enabled in the server firewall (i believe). When the firewall is enabled and we attempt to connect it says "Connection timed out". When the firewall is disabled is says "Connection refused". This seems to suggest that it is the server blocking this rather than something else on the network.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would is to use netstat to determine what, if anything is listening on port 1723 (it should be your VPN server, but could be something else, causing the issue. to do this run the command below

```
netstat -an -o |find /i "listening"
```

This will list all the listening processes, the port they are on and the process ID of the listening process. You can then look in task manager to see what process  that process ID is for.

If that is your VPN server, then you need to look at why it is not responding to requests.